# how to set spacing between bullet and text in word using apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a database which is contains some records. I want to put them in word document using bullets. I wrote this codes for it

```
                        CTAbstractNum cTAbstractNum = CTAbstractNum.Factory.newInstance();
                        cTAbstractNum.setAbstractNumId(BigInteger.valueOf(0));
                        CTLvl cTLvl = cTAbstractNum.addNewLvl();
                        cTLvl.addNewNumFmt().setVal(STNumberFormat.BULLET);
                        cTLvl.addNewLvlText().setVal("•");
                        XWPFAbstractNum abstractNum = new XWPFAbstractNum(cTAbstractNum);
                        XWPFNumbering numbering = document.createNumbering();
                        BigInteger abstractNumID = numbering.addAbstractNum(abstractNum);
                        BigInteger numID = numbering.addNum(abstractNumID); 
                        for (int b=0;b<2;b++) {
                            bulletedPara = document.createParagraph();
                            baslik1 = bulletedPara.createRun();
                            baslik1.setFontSize(10);
                            bulletedPara.setNumID(numID);
                            bulletedPara.setSpacingBetween(0.7);
                            baslik1.setText(answersOil.get(b));
```

[So it comes like this in word document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rIjv.png)

How do I set spacing between bullet and text?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58287694/apache-poi-bullet-spacing/58298403#58298403

Comment: @AxelRichter Thanks, it's better now.