# How to create a Bulleted list in Apache poi?

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-poi

I want to create a list without numbering in a word document using Apache POI. All the examples that I had seen were using XML but I was wondering if there is another way. Because I dont feel comfortable working with it. My goal is to do something like this:

> - Hello
> - World

Comment: Which part of Apache POI are you using to generate the Word file? `HWPF` or `XWPF`?

Comment: Hi @Gagravarr, i' using XWPF

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58287694/apache-poi-bullet-spacing/58298403#58298403

Answer (score 0):

The XML is just well-formed HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>World</li>
</ul>
```