# How do I create a bulleted list in docx with Apache Poi 5?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I know there are lots of answers to this, including some on Stackoverflow:
[Apache POI bullet spacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58287694/apache-poi-bullet-spacing)

#### Problem

I can't get them to work with Apache Poi 5.0.0:

- they compile fine and do create a list
- but the resulting `.docx` file contains a **numbered** list not a *bullet* list.

#### Java Code

```java
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STLevelSuffix;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTAbstractNum;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTLvl;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STNumberFormat;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import java.math.BigInteger;
// https://www.titanwolf.org/Network/q/15e5b419-e50e-426c-895d-d4a47d18e714/y
public class CreateWordTableWithBulletList3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ArrayList < String > documentList = new ArrayList < String > (
            Arrays.asList(
                new String[] {
                    "One",
                    "Two",
                    "Three, new test"
                }));

        CTAbstractNum cTAbstractNum = CTAbstractNum.Factory.newInstance();
        //Next we set the AbstractNumId. This requires care.
        //Since we are in a new document we can start numbering from 0.
        //But if we have an existing document, we must determine the next free number first.
        cTAbstractNum.setAbstractNumId(BigInteger.valueOf(0));

        //Bullet list
        CTLvl cTLvl = cTAbstractNum.addNewLvl();
        cTLvl.addNewNumFmt().setVal(STNumberFormat.BULLET);
        cTLvl.addNewSuff().setVal(STLevelSuffix.SPACE);
        cTLvl.addNewLvlText().setVal("•");

        XWPFAbstractNum abstractNum = new XWPFAbstractNum(cTAbstractNum);
        XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
        XWPFNumbering numbering = document.createNumbering();

        BigInteger abstractNumID = numbering.addAbstractNum(abstractNum);
        BigInteger numID = numbering.addNum(abstractNumID);

        XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
        XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
        run.setText("The list having space between bulltet point and text:");

        for (String string: documentList) {
            paragraph = document.createParagraph();
            paragraph.setNumID(numID);
            // font size for bullet point in half pt
            paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().addNewRPr().addNewSz().setVal(BigInteger.valueOf(48));
            run = paragraph.createRun();
            run.setText(string);
            run.setFontSize(24);
        }

        paragraph = document.createParagraph();

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/tmp/CreateWordSimplestBulletList4.docx");
        document.write(out);
        out.close();
        document.close();

    }
}
```

#### Reproduce

Above program which I tested generates a *numbered* list with Apache Poi 5.0.0.

**Note:** While my original output failed the test in real *Word* (Mac) I am currently testing in *Libre Office (7.1.5.2)* on Fedora (Linux) and on Slack's *Preview Word* function. Both show a numbered list.

Finally I just created a new project, which just contains all the .jar files from poi5 (including all the dependencies but nothing more). That still showed a numbered list in my Libre Office.

#### Resulting output

The `numbering.xml` extracted from .docx:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<w:numbering xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
   <w:abstractNum w:abstractNumId="0">
      <w:lvl>
         <w:numFmt w:val="bullet" />
         <w:suff w:val="space" />
         <w:lvlText w:val="•" />
      </w:lvl>
   </w:abstractNum>
   <w:num w:numId="1">
      <w:abstractNumId w:val="0" />
   </w:num>
</w:numbering>
```

And here is the `document.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
   <w:body>
      <w:p>
         <w:r>
            <w:t>The list having space between bulltet point and text:</w:t>
         </w:r>
      </w:p>
      <w:p>
         <w:pPr>
            <w:numPr>
               <w:numId w:val="1" />
            </w:numPr>
            <w:rPr>
               <w:sz w:val="48" />
            </w:rPr>
         </w:pPr>
         <w:r>
            <w:rPr>
               <w:sz w:val="48" />
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t>One</w:t>
         </w:r>
      </w:p>
      <w:p>
         <w:pPr>
            <w:numPr>
               <w:numId w:val="1" />
            </w:numPr>
            <w:rPr>
               <w:sz w:val="48" />
            </w:rPr>
         </w:pPr>
         <w:r>
            <w:rPr>
               <w:sz w:val="48" />
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t>Two</w:t>
         </w:r>
      </w:p>
      <w:p>
         <w:pPr>
            <w:numPr>
               <w:numId w:val="1" />
            </w:numPr>
            <w:rPr>
               <w:sz w:val="48" />
            </w:rPr>
         </w:pPr>
         <w:r>
            <w:rPr>
               <w:sz w:val="48" />
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t>Three, new test. Lite. Still testing.</w:t>
         </w:r>
      </w:p>
      <w:p />
   </w:body>
</w:document>
```

I think the error is in there somewhere.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I copy/pasted your code, then compile and run using `apache poi 5.0.0`. The result `CreateWordSimplestBulletList4.docx` shows a bullet list in `Microsoft Word 365`, `Libreoffice Writer Version: 6.4.7.2` and `Google Docs`.

Comment: @AxelRichter Odd, I just double checked the code on my computer. So the problem must be with my dependencies or something. Do you have the maven/ant/eclipse/other build file you used, so I can reproduce your build? Or just a list of all the jars you used.

Comment: I doubt this can be a result of dependency mismatches. Then there would be exceptions thrown. Are you sure you are looking at the correct file `/tmp/CreateWordSimplestBulletList4.docx`? If you open it as `ZIP` archive, what do you see in `/word/numbering.xml`?

Comment: @AxelRichter See update with numbers.xml and document.xml

Comment: That is exactly what I get and it works for me. Wild guess: Can it be that your word processing applications don't default the indent level to 0 when not set? Try to set it explicitly: `cTLvl.setIlvl(BigInteger.valueOf(0)); // set indent level 0`.

Comment: @AxelRichter WowcTLvl.setIlvl  fixed it. Now I have a bulleted list thank you. . You can leave that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my examples about creating numbering in `Microsoft Word` I assumed that the indent level will default to 0 if it is not set. I had tested that using all word processing applications I had and it was the case. But that seems not to be the case using all word processing applications which can open `*.docx` files. So explicitly setting the indent level seems to be the most compatible solution.

So in the code for creating the `CTLvl`  do explicitly set the indent level using `cTLvl.setIlvl(BigInteger.valueOf(0)); // set indent level 0`:

```
...
  //Bullet list
  CTLvl cTLvl = cTAbstractNum.addNewLvl();
  cTLvl.setIlvl(BigInteger.valueOf(0)); // set indent level 0
  cTLvl.addNewNumFmt().setVal(STNumberFormat.BULLET);
  cTLvl.addNewSuff().setVal(STLevelSuffix.SPACE);
  cTLvl.addNewLvlText().setVal("•");
...
```

I have updated all my examples accordingly.